# Changing the Look of Proof

Tags: spacing, environments, amsbook

I am using the document class `amsbook`.  I had an issue with my theorems having a good deal of space between the statement of the theorem and the proof.  I have a new theorem style:

```
 \newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}
 {12pt}
 {12pt}
 {}
 {1.27cm}
 {\bf}
 {}
 {.5em}
 {}
```

To correct the spacing issue, someone suggested I add this to my preamble:

```
 \makeatletter
 \renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
   \pushQED{\qed}%
   \normalfont \topsep1\p@\relax
   \trivlist
   \item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape
   #1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces
 }{%
   \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
 }
 \makeatother
```

This fixed the spacing issue.  But, now the word "Proof" is italicized instead of being the block font that comes with the `amsbook` package.  Also, the `proof`s are no longer indented.  I would like to have it look exactly like the `proof` environment from `amsbook`, just without the spacing issue.  Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the definition that "someone" provided is quite different from what's in `amsbook.cls`.
here is the canonical ams `proof` environment, modified to change *only* the spacing above.

```
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep\p@\relax %% this line changed from amsbook
  \trivlist
  \itemindent\normalparindent
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \scshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
```

please note that if this directly follows anything other than a theorem-class object,
the spacing above it will be very, probably too, small.